# Quotient of Second Countable Space

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, quotient-spaces

I'm looking for an example for a ***second countable*** topological space $T$ such that there exist a quotient structure $T/\sim$ which is not second countable.

Does there exist an example where $T$ is a manifold?

Comment: Have you tried proving that a quotient of a second countable space is second countable?

Comment: @ThibautDumont: I don't see any chance to do it: If I start with a countable base $B_T$ of $T$ then every image of an open $U \in B_T$ is "scattered" by the identifications in $T / \sim$ so there is in general no possibility (at least I don't see some) to reach a new basis generated by images of $B_T$ since it's not fine enough to form a basis.

Comment: @ThibautDumont: btw the images do not have to be open if the quotient map isn't saturated. So I guess that a good candidate for a conterexample for the statemant above is a not saturated quotient space :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $T=\mathbb{R}$ in its usual topology (a second countable manifold).

Let $\sim$ be the equivalence relation that identifies $\mathbb{Z}$ to a point and leaves other points untouched: $x \sim y$ iff $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $x \sim y$ iff $x=y$ otherwise. So the classes are exactly $\{x\}$ for all  $x \notin \mathbb{Z}$ adn $\mathbb{Z}$. The map sending $x$ to its class I call $q$ and the set of classes $T/ \sim$ gets the quotient topology w.r.t. $q$.

Then the class $\mathbb{Z} \in T/\sim$ does not have a countable local base (several proofs of this fact can be found on this site, a good one is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1417425/4280), e.g.) so a fortiori this quotient is not second countable (second countable implies first countable).