# What is the standard way of showing that some point does not have a countable basis?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, quotient-spaces

I apologize that I cannot post the exact question and I know this is too vague, but I am asked to show that, around some point $x$ in some quotient space, it does not have a countable basis around that point.
I was guessing that, then around $x$, it does have to have an uncountable basis. But I'm getting nowhere from here, and I cannot really think of any trick.

Maybe I need to use the contradiction, but I'm not sure what "having countably many basis" will imply. Could someone give me any input?

Comment: It will depend on knowing what defines your topology.  Of course metric topologies cannot satisfy your condition.

Comment: @hardmath It is a quotient space formed from Euclidean space, with some identification. Could you just throw out some keywords just as an inspiration?

Comment: A likely approach is to let $\mathscr{B}=\{B_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ be an arbitrary countable family of open nbhds of the point and show how to construct an open nbhd of the point that does not contain any of the sets $B_n$. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1417388/why-is-mathbbr-sim-not-first-countable-at-0-where-x-sim-y-leftri/1417425#1417425) is an answer in which I used that idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commonest way I've seen is a kind of diagonalisation argument: given countably many $(B_n)_n$ open neighbourhoods of $x$ we can find an open neighbourhood $O$ of $x$ such that $B_n \nsubseteq O$ for all $n$.

You could also contradict a consequence of first countability: e.g. $x \in \overline{A}$ for some set $A$ while there is no sequence from $A$ converging to $x$.

It all depends on who the topology is defined. For quotients the first way is the most common, maybe because open sets are easy to recognise.