# The equivalence class $\mathbb{Z}$ has no countable neighbourhood basis in the quotient space $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

I'm trying to prove that the class $\mathbb{Z}$ has no countable neighbourhood basis in the quotient space $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$. I started with taking a neighbourhood basis $\mathcal{U} = \{ U_{i} : i \in I \}$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$. I'd like to prove that $\mathcal{U}$ is uncountable but I'm stucked at this point. I'll appreciate it if someone could give a hint on how to proceed/prove this. Thank you.

$\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$ here is the partition $\{ \{ x \} : x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z} \} \cup \{ \mathbb{Z} \}$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: it has a countable neighborhoood basis: $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \cong S^1$

Comment: @psl2Z no, $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$ means the set $\mathbb{Z}$ is collapsed to a point. Hence the class where a non-integer $x$ belongs to is a singleton, namely $\{ x \}$.

Comment: Take a look at our guidelines for how to [avoid "I'm not sure where to start"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933) questions. For example, I'm sure you were able to write down the definitions and convert them into a proof strategy, so adding that to your question would be a good start.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ is. Since $\mathbb Z$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb R$, the reader is tempted to understand it as the *quotient group*.

Comment: Suggestion: Can you be more explicit about what a typical neighborhood $U_i$ of $\mathbf{Z}$ looks like?

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1417425/1016538